# How to fix: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'optimizers' in JupyterNotebook (using colab.research)

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, attributeerror

I am trying to run my neural network in colab.research page, but I am still getting error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'optimizers'` at this line:

```
opt = tensorflow.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.00001, decay=1e-6)
```

My importing part from the code:

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import optimizers
import os
```

Tensorflow version:

```
print(tensroflow.__version__) # 1.15.0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

optimizers is part of the keras library. Either do

```
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
```

And then use

```
optimizers.RMSprop()
```

in your code
Or

```
opt = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.RMSprop()
```

Comment: opt = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.RMSprop()

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
opt = tensorflow.compat.v1.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.00001, decay=1e-6)
```

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/RMSPropOptimizer